# Is there any way to enable function description of GAS function on VScode?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, visual-studio-code

I installed GAS package from command line

```
npm install --save @types/google-apps-script
```

and VScode autocomplete only tell about parameter type like this
[image]

not what parameter are using for and more description like in web editor
[image]

is there any way to make VScode suggestion look like web editor?
Or there is no way to do this?

Comment: Someone has to document all those types, I think.  Maybe there's a automated way, but you'll have better luck creating a github issue in defintelyTyped

Comment: I'm actually working on a script to pull down all of the documentation from the GAS documentation into a Spreadsheet. Then we could use that to enhance the NPPM package. :)

Comment: This question is discussed in the community [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217630/google-apps-script-chat-community)

Comment: Thanks for all your answer. I hope google make this available soon.